# empty template for a customized Tuple

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I tried to defined some customized Tuple based on the some examples in "The C++ programming language 4th" but I think I am little confused about the empty brace syntax for template.

I get both compile errors for below two cases but the compiler reports the different error messages so I am just wondering is there any semantic difference between these two cases?

`template<>
struct Tuple<> { Tuple() {} };`

Compiler report `Tuple is not a class template`

`template<>
struct Tuple { Tuple() {} };`

Compiler reports `explicit specialization of non-template Tuple`

Comment: What is the Tuple template for which you are specializing?

Comment: Post the complete code or we can't help.